# GeoNear with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb

This is my mongoose schema -

```
var userDestinationSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    uid: String,                
    update_time: Date,          

    location:{                  //<INDEXED as 2d>
        lon: Number,
        lat: Number
    }
});



var userDestinationModel = mongoose.model('userDestinationModel', userDestinationSchema);
```

How do I query the model for geoNear?

I tried doing this and it ain't working.

```
userDestinationModel.geoNear([parseInt(req.params.lon,10),parseInt(req.params.lat,10)],
              { maxDistance : 50, spherical : true }, 
              function(err, results, stats) {
                   console.log(results);
                });
```

maxDistance : 50

What is the unit? Km?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the distance part, but I've never used `geoNear` with Mongoose I'm afraid - a good way to tell if the issue lies in how you are calling things in Mongoose versus the query itself would be to try it on the `mongo` shell first to verify that it is returning the results you expect there.

In terms of the distance, for legacy 2d points (which you appear to be using), the `$maxdistance` is specified in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) - there is a [page here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/#calculate-distance-using-spherical-geometry) which outlines how to use radians with spherical geometry calculations.  If you use GeoJSON instead (which I would recommend), then it is specified in meters ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/)).

Answer (score -1):

max distance is in meters in geoNear.

```
userDestinationModel.geoNear(
   {
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },//lat long
     spherical: true,
     maxDistance: 50 //meter
   }
)
```